# Hover to a div, change the color of the <a> element inside this div

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is quite easy, my code is as below:

html:

```
<div class="outer">
    <a href="">line 1</a>
    <a>line 2</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.outer:hover{
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

The problem is, when I add `href=""` to the , the hover can't work.  If I remove the `href=""`, when I move my mouse pointer to the div, the hover effect works.
Souce is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/aFY3v/)

Anybody know what's the reason?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the color of the `<a>` element when the `<div>` is hovered over:

```
.outer:hover a{
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

Fiddle: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aFY3v/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
.outer:hover a{
    color:#ff0000;
}
```